# Existence of transversal loops on a vector field without singular points on $\mathbb{T}^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, smooth-manifolds

Let $X$ be a smooth vector field on $\mathbb{T}^2$ without singular points and periodic orbits. Then by this theorem

> **Theorem:(Poincaré, Denjoy)** Every non-singular $\mathcal{C}^2$ vector field on a compact surface that has no periodic orbits is topologically equivalent to a linear flow on a torus with the irrational slope,

$X$ is topologically equivalent to the irrational flow. It is trivial that if $Y$ is a irrational flow on $\mathbb{T}^2$ then there exists two $\mathcal{C}^1$ loops $$\alpha_1,\alpha_2 : \mathbb{S}^1\to \mathbb{T}^2$$
with $\alpha_1(0) = \alpha_2(0) = p$, such that $\{Y(\alpha_i(t)),\alpha_i'(t)\}$ is a basis of $T_{\alpha(t)} \mathbb{T}^2$, $\forall$ $t$ $\in$ $\mathbb{S}^1$, and $[\alpha_1 (t)], [\alpha_2 (t)]$ are generators of the group $\pi_1(\mathbb{T}^2,p)$.

> **My Doubt:** Using that $X$ is topologically equivalent to $Y$, is it possible to guarantee that there exists  two $\mathcal{C}^1$ loops $$\beta_1,\beta_2 : \mathbb{S}^1\to \mathbb{T}^2$$
>   with $\beta_1(0) = \beta_2(0) = p$, such that $\{X(\beta_i(t)),\beta_i'(t)\}$ is a basis of $T_{\alpha(t)} \mathbb{T}^2$, $\forall$ $t$ $\in$ $\mathbb{S}^1$, and $[\beta_1 (t)], [\beta_1 (t)]$ are generators of the group $\pi_1(\mathbb{T}^2,p)$?

Comment: When you say topologically equivalent, do you mean there is a homeomorphism from $X$ to the torus taking the given flow to a standard linear flow of irrational slope?

Comment: If $Y$ is the standard linear flow of irrational slope, $\phi$ and $\psi$ are, respectively, the flow of the vector fields $Y$ and $X$, then there are a homeomorphism $h:\mathbb{T}^2 \to \mathbb{T}^2$ and a continuous function $\tau: \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{T}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, crescent on the first entry ($\tau(\cdot, p)$ is a bijection for every $p \in \mathbb{T}^2$ fixed), such that $\phi(t,h(p) ) = h \circ \psi (\tau(t,p), p) $

Comment: I would imagine you could use something like Stone-Weierstrass to show that the desired result holds up to an arbitrarily small homotopy of $X$, then show that for a sufficiently small $C^1$ homotopy the desired properties are preserved. There are some troublesome details to flesh out though...